# How to block IPs for POST requests, but not GET?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a website where I'm getting quite a lot of comment spam. Looking at the IP addresses the spam originates from, they're mostly from countries where it's unlikely any real humans would want to interact with my English-language website, so it makes sense for me to simply block them.

This should be quite straightforward, however I'd like it if traffic from these countries could actually view my content, just not access the comment, registration etc. forms. So effectively I want to allow them to make GET method requests, but not POST method ones.

Ideally, I'd like to do this in the .htaccess file for the site rather than actually coding it into the PHP scripts that power the site. After a bit of searching, I found what I thought was exactly what I needed: . It appeared that I could do exactly as described above with:

```
# Block China, Russia etc. from POSTs and similar methods
<Limit POST PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from 210.5.214.128/29
deny from 210.89.69.160/28
# Hundreds more lines...
# My current IP (sample provided here, actual used in reality), to test
deny from 100.100.100.100
allow from all
</Limit> 

# Allow anyone to do GETs and HEADs
<Limit GET HEAD>
order deny,allow
allow from all
</Limit>
```

But it's not having the desired effect. I can do GET requests (as desired), but POSTs also still work as normal where I would expect a 403 Forbidden error perhaps.

If I don't use the  tag and put my IP in the deny list, it does successfully prevent me from accessing the site (both GET and POST).

Can anyone advise me as to what I need to change?

Comment: `Ideally, I'd like to do this in the .htaccess file for the site rather than actually coding it into the PHP scripts` - why? The latter is faster and easier to maintain.

Comment: For me, the htaccess option is easier to maintain as my source for unwanted IPs provides them in this format. To achieve the desired result at PHP-level, I'd need to either hard-code these in as an array (bit of a hassle, but possible), parse an uploaded text file containing the IPs (slightly slower I expect), or put them in a database and get them from there (almost certainly less effecient).

Also, the .htaccess option allows me to do this sitewide, without having to include this function in every PHP script.

Comment: Go do some benchmarking, and note what's happenning with the memory usage while you run it. Even assuming that the server restarts are not a problem, the performance will be.

Answer (score 3):

Change the order of allow deny like this:

```
<Limit POST PUT DELETE>
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from 210.5.214.128/29
deny from 210.89.69.160/28
# Hundreds more lines...
# My current IP (sample provided here, actual used in reality), to test
deny from 100.100.100.100
</Limit> 

<Limit GET HEAD>
order deny,allow
allow from all
</Limit>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Block backend repertory eg: /wp-admin except for allow IP (even if you have the password)

```
<Limit POST PUT DELETE>
 order deny,allow
 deny from all
 #allow from localhost
 #allow from 127.0.0.1
 allow from xxx.xxx.xx.xx
</Limit>

# Allow anyone to do GETs and HEADs
<Limit GET HEAD>
 order deny,allow
 allow from all
</Limit>
```

Comment: Please write it in English and remove `Jack if you're still there`. Because it might be useful for peoples other than `Jack`.