# Can Tableau be used in customer-facing and SaaS web applications?

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, business-intelligence, tableau-api

I was hoping someone could help me answer a couple of questions regarding Tableau. I am not as familiar with the platform, but I have a client who is looking for a reporting/analytics/data visualization platform that they could use for many of the internal apps (for their employees) and external (customer facing internet with login) applications.

The driver is that each of their internal teams has used many disparate technologies such as SSRS, Crystal, custom ASP.NET controls (Kendo/Telerik, etc), but now they have the opportunity to choose a common platform that could serve most/all of the future reporting and data visualization needs for enterprise and customer facing solutions.

They are looking for a platform that provides everything from simple grids with basic filter/sort/group, all the way to rich charting and ad-hoc reporting with slicing and dicing of data.

They will not always be creating dashboards in these apps since they are customer-facing, but they may want to have dashboards for internal (intranet) apps. They will definitely want the ability to build true internal BI dashboards to report on data from all these online apps across all customers, to whom they provide their SaaS/customer-facing web apps.

One of our main concerns revolves around security of data, as some of these customer-facing web apps are multi-tenant, so we'd need to ensure that data is always filtered by the client tenant id.  Also we have a very customized security model, with data driven roles, permissions that may prevent showing certain types of data (e.g. SSN, Salary, etc) etc.

**Does Tableau fits this model, can it meet most/all of these requirements, or is it meant more for internal data?**

Answer (score 2):

It should be quite possible by setting up a reverse proxy that would front end your multi tenant web application. There is a [document](http://community.tableausoftware.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/202389-16289/Tableau%20Server%20-%20Setting%20up%20an%20Apache%20Server%20as%20a%20Proxy%20with%20SSL.docx) on how to setup Apache as reverse proxy with Tableau with/without SSL.

I am familiar with how to configure Apache as reverse proxy and so here are the details with [Apache Web server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) on how to setup reverse proxy rules.

There may be some documentation for front ending with IIS/Nginx so you should do some googling by yourself.

You need to harden your webserver configuration by limiting access from the external firewall to read only pages and the internal user can access allpages. Since you mentioned that the external users are allowed access to readonly pages, I presume all the requests from external requests will be only GET requests and a few PUT/POST requests when users choose to use filters. So you can [block external users from any request except GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534674/how-to-block-ips-for-post-requests-but-not-get). Exceptions should be made for the pages that allow applying filters and grouping.

In your mutitenant application make sure you refer to the tableau URL's by the apache server url that is exposed to the outside world. If any url not configured in apache is used, users will recieve a access denied error. You need to create a role that has readonly access to tableau pages for external users. To address mulitenancy you need to set a cookie or something to identify the tenant and something similar to identify the user. To filter SSN and some more information you can use mod_proxy_html which filters content. You can also use [mod_security module of Apache](http://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/ModSecurity-Frequently-Asked-Questions-%28FAQ%29) to block SSNs and Credit Card Numbers.

References:

- [Configuring Apache Server as Proxy with Tableau](http://community.tableausoftware.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/202389-16289/Tableau%20Server%20-%20Setting%20up%20an%20Apache%20Server%20as%20a%20Proxy%20with%20SSL.docx)
- [Apache mod Proxy documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)
- [Blocking POST requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534674/how-to-block-ips-for-post-requests-but-not-get)
- [mod_security FAQs](http://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/ModSecurity-Frequently-Asked-Questions-%28FAQ%29)

Answer (score 1):

Yes to most of your questions -- with just a little fine print.

First remember Tableau is primarily about visualizing data, so it is great for publishing readonly interactive views of data. If you want allow end users to edit data, you'll have to do that by another means. Fortunately, the Tableau JavaScript API lets you interact closely with Tableau with your custom Javascript code. So if your needs are mostly about visualization, but want want to be able to trigger some custom code to modify data in some of your apps, you should be fine. But Tableau is not designed for creating custom CRUD apps as a rule.

The great thing about Tableau server is that many people can learn to use it and publish their own visualizations -- even if they don't know how to program. That doesn't mean they will win visualization design awards the first time, or that they shouldn't learn something about how databases work if they want have good performance. But it does mean the people that know their data best can learn to design and publish their own visualizations without having to wait three months on a backlog queue so the one IT guy can change the color of a button or add a field. It still would be good to get good system, database and visualization folks to help train, organize data, set governance and security rules, optimize, etc, but business users can learn to be the ones with hands on control over how their information is presented. That's a good thing.

The security question has several moving parts, and usually there are usually good answers from Tableau depending on what you're trying to accomplish. Tableau server does support multi-tenancy using sites. There is fairly flexible permissions and group policy system. It can use SAML for authentication, and has several features providing access to specific to the user/tenant. It works with almost every database, and you can in some cases push your security enforcement to the database server -- SQL server for instance. There is a trusted ticket feature where you can defer some authorization decisions to another server, say a web portal server. Useful when Tableau visualizations are embedded in some other web page.

Most security use cases can be supported out of the box, but there are some complex custom access control situations that are tricky to implement currently in Tableau server. Nothing you've listed sounds out of the normal swim lane, but the only way to know whether your security model is too complex is to dive into the details. Hopefully they will release a custom access control API for users who want to extend it.

Comment: thanks, Alex.  I don't have a requirement for modifying data from the reporting tool. My scenario would embed Tableau into a web app which is a multi-tenant SaaS app.  I would not want the app users to know about tableau, nor would i want them to be logging into some other server for reporting.  This would be the job of my app to integrate and pull the reports they can access while giving them the ability to change grouping/filtering/sorting (slice/dice) and saving their customizations of the report as a personal version or copy of the original report.

Answer (score 1):

At the high level, you sure can use Tableau to build customer-facing dashboards. You can quickly build and deploy those and as others mentioned, you can iFrame them with Javascript APIs, you can customize most of it. But it doesn't provide complete flexibility for user interaction, which you can if you use other technologies. Other options include hand coding framework and then using charting applications.
For simple dashboards, Tableau would be the obvious choice if you have already bought core-licenses. But when looking at what's going on in the industry, Tableau will not be able to fulfill all needs. 
If using Tableau
1. Building Charts/Tables/Visualization is a super simple, efficient way.
2. You can expose low grained data to customers, because of Tableau's propitiatory columnar database engine, you can potentially expose millions of records via a dashboard.
3. You can use Tableau's security and access control mechanism.
4. As other user mentioned, you can use trusted ticketing mechanism to integrate easily with other applications (portals etc).

Challenges with Tableau approach.
1. If you have late arriving transactions (in Internet world it's so common to mark a click as fraudulent after few days) with late arriving transactions, you have to have full refresh the extracts, which means if you are showing say 13 months worth of data, you have refresh it all, all the time. Now with bigData, business needs all data all the time, which means you would end up extracting millions of  records, throughout the day.
2. Very little flexibility in user interactions, like menus,drop downs etc. you have to work with what's been provided by Tableau.
3. If you have multiple charts on same dashboard page, not so user friendly way to download underlying data.
4. Many other challenges, in laying out visualizations on dashboard page, as there is no easy way to control canvas with pixel control, white spaces etc.

You should be very careful, after analyzing your use case, whether Tableau would be the right product before you invest in it.

Tableau's primary power comes from its desktop tool for data visualization/exploration and not from pre-built dashboards.
Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Since Tableau public is also based on Tableau, I assume that you can put your dashboards in public using your own Tableau infrastructure.